# Texlipse document class in java editor

Tags: java, eclipse, texlipse

I have to make a calibration certificate over latex with respect to the data generated in a java project ,so i have installed texipse into my eclipse and i have set the path to MikTex libraries and created a latex file in the same java project .My doubt is, how can I generate pdf when i run the java project that has texlipse file inside the same project.

Comment: What do you mean by calibration certificate? Is this some file that is created in the java build? Or an additional documentation?

Comment: additional documentation and it is similar to a data sheet

Comment: I think that it is difficult to have a mixture of two project types. What is your build tool? Maven? Gradle? It might be better to integrate the LaTeX compiling into the build process.